# ASP.Net Application : localhost redirected you too many times

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

My ASP.Net-4 web application cannot run, it's just showing error "localhost redirected you too many times".
The project was working properly. Newly I have created a new page, and I have run the project successfully by skipping the authentication phase for few times. After then its showing the error and cannot run it any how. I tried by excluding the page from project, but same error. I cleared cookies, cashes, even I have reinstalled the browser also, but did not work.

I'll appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us your code regarding this matter? From the sound of it, there is some logic that is recursively hitting your redirect.

Comment: I have found the problematic point, in my default page i used a button to navigate a page, but there is an error on that page. When I removed the button from my default page the application is running properly. Although my new page is not opening due to error "A server error occurred when we tried to complete your request. Please try again after some time. If the problem persists, please contact support.", but it's another thread.

Comment: Did you use cookie authentication? when user access your webapp. the server will return token in response and redirect back. But the request didn't send token to your server, then it get infinite loop. You could troubleshooting the redirection with fiddler. It would probably have something to do with your deployment architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting too many times accidently. When you redirect to authorize page it redirects you backward because of unauthorized access. This is because you are trying to by pass the authentication.